# Aligning ImageView to LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, alignment, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, layoutparams

I need to programmatically align an ImageView to the bottom of a LinearLayout.

I, of course, already tried to add the ImageView as a child of the LinearLayout, but the image get shrinked (cause the LinearLayout is smaller than the image), and I need the image not be resized, only bottom-aligned.

I also tried this :

```
    RelativeLayout main_layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
    LinearLayout line_0_layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.line_0_layout);

    ImageView horse_img = new ImageView(getActivity());
    horse_img.setImageResource(R.drawable.horse);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layout_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, line_0_layout.getId());

    horse_img.setLayoutParams(layout_params);
    main_layout.addView(horse_img);
```

but it doesn't work : the image is added to the view but not aligned to the LinearLayout.

It seems simple question, but it's not.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is `line_0_layout` a child of `main_layout`?  Because the code you posted can only work if that is the case.  ALIGN_BOTTOM is defined as a rule that aligns a child's bottom edge with another child's bottom edge.  I don't think (but I'm not sure) that what you are trying to do is possible if `horse_img` and `line_0_layout` don't share a `RelativeLayout` parent.

Answer (score 0):

```
layout_params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, line_0_layout.getId());
```

Comment: Thanks, but this aligns the ImageView to the bottom of the main layout, not to the bottom of the line_0_layout layout.

Comment: No luck neither. The layout is not anchored to the line_0_layout layout.